# Issues with the Sample Sample-chatv2-android and XMPP chat server

Tags: quickblox

I was able to get Sample-chat version 2 android sample to run. The one-on-one chat function in the app works fine but the chatroom functionality does not work most of the time.

Since the chatroom functionality works sometimes the code seems to be fine. By debugging I was saw that the chatroom messages are not received from the XMPP server. When a chatroom is joined then sometimes the joining seems to be not successful and the older, saved messages in the chatroom are not received.

SO it seems like this is an isssue with the Quickblox XMPP chat server, since the sample app seems to work half of the time. Please let me know if the chatroom functionality is QuickBlox works properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question in regards sample 2.
Unfortunately some bugs are possible in this sample.
We are creating new sample for Android chat, so soon we will share it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [new SDK and chat sample](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-chat). It was recently released and contains several improvements.